# How to find count of transaction of type1 and type2 for each customer in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot-table

I have a customer table:

```
id   name
1    customer1
2    customer2
3    customer3
```

and a transaction table:

```
id   customer   amount   type
1    1          10       type1
2    1          15       type1
3    1          15       type2
4    2          60       type2
5    3          23       type1
```

What I want my query to return is the following table

```
name        type1    type2
customer1   2        1
customer2   0        1
customer3   1        0
```

Which shows that customer1 has made two transactions of type1 and 1 transaction of type2 and so forth.

Is there a query which I can use to obtain this result or do I have to use procedural code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
select c.id as customer_id
   , c.name as customer_name
   , sum(case when t.`type` = 'type1' then 1 else 0 end) as count_of_type1
   , sum(case when t.`type` = 'type2' then 1 else 0 end) as count_of_type2
from customer c
   left join `transaction` t
   on c.id = t.customer
group by c.id, c.name
```

This query needs to iterate only once over the join.

Comment: using `IF(t.type = 'type1', 1, 0)` is a bit more succinct, IMO, but +1 since this is the way to do it

Comment: oh actually, since "booleans" in MySQL are actually just 1 and 0, you don't even need the IF/CASE statement at all: `SUM(t.type = 'type1')` will do it.

Comment: Yeah. But even after a few years of C experience, I feel a little bit uncomfortable when I see code like `some_array[x == 1]`... :-) But I agree on the `IF` thingy being a little bit less verbose

Comment: Wouldn't the 'case when' part only check one of the many columns in the transaction table for the customer

Comment: @andho: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Is there more than a single column in the `transaction` table, where a customer ID may be found? If so, there is nothing in your post which would suggest so.

Comment: @Dirk: no I just didn't understand the SQL but it works as expected. I thought the CASE WHEN clause will only check the first column of the GROUP

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  name, 
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    transaction t
        WHERE   t.customer = c.id
                AND t.type = 'type1'
        ) AS type1,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    transaction t
        WHERE   t.customer = c.id
                AND t.type = 'type2'
        ) AS type2
FROM    customer c
```

To apply `WHERE` conditions to these columns use this:

```
SELECT  name
FROM    (
        SELECT  name, 
                (
                SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    transaction t
                WHERE   t.customer = c.id
                        AND t.type = 'type1'
                ) AS type1,
                (
                SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    transaction t
                WHERE   t.customer = c.id
                        AND t.type = 'type2'
                ) AS type2
        FROM    customer c
        ) q
WHERE   type1 > 3
```

Comment: Yes this is a good solution but is there a shorter query if there are many types? Because I am working on many types in a huge dataset

Comment: What you want is called pivoting. No, there is no simple way to do in in `MySQL`. Are you sure you need these type as columns, not rows?

Comment: Yeah having them as rows will make everything much easier but don't necessarily need them as such

Comment: It seems I am unable to use the new columns in a WHERE clause

Comment: `@andho`: wrap the whole query into a subquery and select from it.

Answer (score 1):

dirk beat me to it ;)

Similar but will work in mysql 4.1 too.

```
Select c.name,
sum(if(type == 1,1,0)) as `type_1_total`,
sum(if(type == 2,1,0)) as `type_2_total`,
from 
customer c
join transaction t on (c.id = t.customer)
;
```